# Saving every input in local storage and console log all of the entered input

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a problem where I currently have a few input fields (verzender, bedrag, ontvanger), if you enter and 'submit' the form, the inputs get stored in the localStorage, but if I console log the data, it only shows the last one that got stored, and I would like to have every input that is ever entered, to be stored.

Does anyone know the solution to this or what I'm doing wrong?

**My current code**

```
function submitTransaction() {
    const bedrag = document.getElementById("bedrag").value;
    const verzender = document.getElementById("verzender").value;
    const ontvanger = document.getElementById("ontvanger").value;
    const transactie = new Transactie();
    transactie.print(bedrag, verzender, ontvanger);
    localStorage.setItem("Transactie", `${verzender} send ${bedrag} bits to ${ontvanger}`);
}

console.log(localStorage.getItem("Transactie"));
```

Comment: localStorage.setItem("Transactie", value) - set this value to key. It does not append it. You may need to store an array of items

Answer (score 0):

Try saving data as array, like the following

Set Item in localstorage

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(arr));
```

get Item from localstorage

```
let arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
```

hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, I need an array, but if I redefine it like that, that array will be empty everytime again right, so it won't leave the old values, right?